# Better way to filter join against a list of values in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

In my schema, a Hardware item may have zero or more Mods recorded against it. I'm trying to filter a query based on an exact match against a list of mods. For example, I might want to filter for Hardware which has mods [2,3,5], and no others.

At the moment, I'm grouping and counting to check that the number of mods is correct, then adding a filter in a for loop to match the exact mod numbers:

```
...
query = query.join(Hardware).join(Mod)
query = query.group_by(Tag.tag_id).having(len(v['m']) == func.count(Mod.mod_number))
for m in v['m']:
    query = query.filter(Hardware.mods.any(mod_number=m))
...
```

Is there a better way to express this using SQLAlchemy? In particular, the documentation recommends against using `func.count()` because it fails in some corner cases..

My schema looks like this:

```
Base = declarative_base()


class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tag'
    tag_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    order_code = Column(String, nullable=False)
    version = Column(String, nullable=False)
    status = Column(String, nullable=False)
    comments = Column(String)
    software = relationship(
        "Software",
        backref="tag",
        collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection('artefact'),
    )
    hardware = relationship(
        "Hardware",
        backref="tag",
        collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection('artefact'),
    )
    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint('order_code', 'version'),
    )

    def as_dict(self):
        d = as_dict_columns(self)
        d['software'] = {s: as_dict_columns(self.software[s]) for s in self.software}
        d['hardware'] = {h: self.hardware[h].as_dict() for h in self.hardware}
        return d


class Software(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'software'
    software_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('tag.tag_id'))
    artefact = Column(String, nullable=False)
    version = Column(String, nullable=False)
    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint('tag_id', 'artefact'),
    )

    def __str__(self):
        """ This is to deal with Jinja2/SQLAlchemy wackiness """
        return self.version


class Hardware(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'hardware'
    hardware_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('tag.tag_id'))
    product_id = Column(String, nullable=True)
    artefact = Column(String, nullable=False)
    version = Column(String, nullable=False)
    mods = relationship("Mod", backref="hardware")
    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint('tag_id', 'product_id'),
    )

    def as_dict(self):
        d = as_dict_columns(self)
        d['mods'] = self.__list_mods__()
        return d

class Mod(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mod'
    hardware_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('hardware.hardware_id'), primary_key=True)
    mod_number = Column('mod_number', Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint('hardware_id', 'mod_number'),
    )
```

Comment: how are Hardware/Tag/Mod related?

Comment: @van, I've added my schema to the end of the question.

Comment: Thanks. `Mod` is still missing though

Comment: Oops, thanks. I've added Mod as well.

Comment: I see. With this model you have got pretty good solution in my opinion. Unless you need to filter for HW with many Mods, in which case you will end up with the SELECT statement with many sub-queries.

Comment: Thanks for your help van. Actually yes, I did end up needing to filter on any combination of hardware and mods, and like you said I ended up with many sub-queries.. were you going to suggest a model change? I ended up with a huge SELECT that I never would have written by hand, but SQLAlchemy made it easy with for loops. So (being new to SQLAlchemy) I feel like it's definitely more expressive than SQL, but maybe it's just giving me the power to create an unholy mess more efficiently :)

Comment: Well, it is hard to recommend anything without seeing the larger picture. Given that Mods are just plain numbers, you could store them as comma-separated (sorted) string column, in which case your filter will get trivial WHERE clause. However, again, I do not think I can judge how "hacky" is this 'hack'... :)

Comment: Thanks again. That seems pretty reasonable. I've done something similar before using GROUP_CONCAT to build a CSV string and using a simple WHERE clause like you said.